# Best way to query dataverse with Office Addin

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins, dataverse

I need my Office Add-In to read a table in Dataverse. I am reading about setting up SSO in my Office Add-In but I'm not accessing MS Graph - I want to be able to access the data verse web api without the user having to log on again even if they are in the Outlook app.

I am not sure which way to go - as I can use NPM packages to get it working with an App registration but I don't want to go and put my secret info (client secrets etc) in the office UI app.

I just want to know if anyone has done this before and therefore the best practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You need Application user in Azure. This application user will have permission grant to access Dataverse.
2. Once you have application user, you will have clientId and secret of that application user.
3. You will then authenticate with it i.e you will have Token.
4. If you want to consume dataverse via this application user using cloud flow, there is directly an option to run your cloud flow as this application user.
5. You can then easily call your cloud flow from any of your other PowerApps application and it will always run against particualr user.

[Step by step to connect to D365 with a client_secret to use APIs](https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/step-step-connect-d365-clientsecret-use-apis)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SSO is exactly what you need to reach the Graph API from Office web add-ins. The best way for an Office Add-in to get authorized access to Microsoft Graph is to use the credentials from the user's Office sign on. This enables them to access their Microsoft Graph data without needing to sign in a second time. Read more about that in the [Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph) article.

For Outlook add-ins, be sure to enable `Modern Authentication` for the Microsoft 365 tenancy. For information about how to do this, see [Exchange Online: How to enable your tenant for modern authentication](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32711.exchange-online-how-to-enable-your-tenant-for-modern-authentication.aspx).

Comment: Yes but I want to query data verse and not really look up the users manager etc….

Comment: `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that out of the box.

Comment: So if I get it to authorise to a service application in azure by sso .. then I can link that spn to the data verse and then use web api to connect to data verse !! Okay I’ll give it a whirl !! Thanks !!